Identify 5-pin IC with "GAKSSR" marking
I am tearing down the broken Mantis BlackbeardX dry fire laser system. I can identify the  burned resistor R8 and I am struggling to identify the component U4, which has GAKSSR written on it. There is also the same second one - U2.


It's an Onsemi NCP718ASN500T1G 5V LDO regulator.


(Source: lcsc.com)
